# Selling software to a company? What copyright should I do?

Tags: small-business

I have developed an android app related to industrial automation. A service provider automation company wants to purchase it from me and sell it to there clients! I have a doubt should I add my name or my company logo on the app with the  company like I have seen in some app that power by google,android etc written. I was just a developer but now I m getting in to professional business and no idea, how it works? 
Thanks!

Comment: Just ask the service provider if they want to put their own brand on the application or if they want to be a distributor for the developer's brand. It is possible for them to put their own brand on the application without buying exclusive distribution of the application. Or they might want exclusive distribution.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, congratulations!

You **really** need to talk to a trusted relative (because you're probably young, and that trusted relative will hopefully have more experience and be a second pair of eyes having your best interest in mind), and get an accountant and contract lawyer, because you need to decide whether to:

1. sell it to them outright, lock, stock and barrel for a single lump sum, or
2. license it to them exclusively for an annual fee, or
3. license it to them **un**exclusively, so that you can sell it to **other** service provider automation companies.

Each has it's advantages and disadvantages.

Also, an important question is whether they'd expect you to maintain it for them, and how much they'd pay you for such maintenance.

(Changing subjects: I'm dubious as to whether or not this is really on-topic for the **Personal** Finance & Money site.)

Comment: Trusted relative? Why not a professional?

Comment: @DJClayworth I mentioned **both**.

Comment: Great. Means there will be two types of business. For exclusive still if I give them their brand name on app, will I be able to send it to other costumer with different logo! Like for example siemens tia portal. Automation companies, install it with there own name but still software is from siemens! With logo of different company

Comment: "_For exclusive still if I give them their brand name on app, will I be able to send it to other costumer with different logo!_" That has nothing to do with "the logo" but depends **entirely** on the deal you strike. If you give them **exclusive** rights (either for a lump sum, or ongoing license fees and/or royalties), then you won't be able to make it available to others (whatever logo it carries).